Turn curves into points then back into curves that won't connect the separated curves at the tips
I'm super new to geometry nodes, but I need a way to turn curves into points then back into curves that won't connect the separated curves at the tips, Points to Curves seems to be the node but I'm missing something.

I'm reading through a similar question, but everyone over there is suggesting not converting to points, other suggest replacing the curve to point nodes for Resample Curve, but I explicitly need them to be points (so I can manipulate them. I tried resample and just didn't suit my needs) and then to become a curve again.  "Capture the spline index before Curve to Points and use it as Curve Group ID." is a simple fix and seems to work, hopeful that's all it takes.

Capture the spline index before Curve to Points and use it as Curve Group ID.

This question is similar to: Curve Group ID from Curve to Points: How to preserve separate splines in Geometry Node?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

yes, I'm readding through that question, its similar but everyone over there is suggesting not converting to points, some suggest replacing the curve to point nodes  for resampling curve, but in my case i explicitly said i need them to be points (so i can manipulate them, hard to explain trust me, i tried resample and just didn't suit my needs) and then to become a curve again.

@spatialed there isn't a single known workflow where converting to points and back would be needed. Therefore we're asking you to tell us what the workflow is, otherwise it's pointless to create content that allows a non-existent workflow, because posts on BSE are supposed to solve repeatable problems.

We can't really help without knowing your workflow. What if you need the solution because you're exporting the points to a 3rd party software? Quellenform's solution wouldn't work then, not without somehow exporting the captured attribute.

ok, sorry i didn't think id be necessary and wanted to simplify the task as much as possible, ill explain

i need to convert to points so i can manipulate their position on the curves tangent cotangent and normal using a noise texture, then i need to be able to turn it back into curve so i use its new tangent cotangent and normal in order to add a second level of detail to it, (i just cant do this with resample cuz it doesn't have tangent/normal outputs like 'curve to points' does). (all of this i have already achieved), but in the end i need it as a curve object so i can do normal curve stuff with it like turn it into mesh and give it a profile. capturing the spline index seems to do the trick

See, now we know your actual problem is accessing the normal/tangent, just use the "normal" node and the "curve tangent" node.

well that would require me to pretty much remake my node setup, but rn have managed to get all of the functionality i just explained using 'curve to points' which was already difficult enough , and its working the way i want it except for the fact that the tips are conjoined, never the less if there is any other alternate route, ill sure try it next, someone also mentioned 'sample curve' .

Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

This sounds like the XY Problem. In your attempts to avoid remaking your node tree you've omitted your real issue from us, for which there likely is an easier and quicker solution.

The answer was simple: Capture the spline index before Curve to Points and use it as the Curve Group ID in the Points to Curve node:


This is Option 2 of the accepted answer I linked above which you claimed to not be solving your problem.
